# Vector groups' spans - proof of direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

There's a problem in a homework assignment I'm having a bit of trouble with - I think I have the correct answer but if someone could confirm or deny that it would help. Here's the problem:

Prove or disprove:

let $V$ be a linear vector space. If $S,T\subseteq V$ are non-empty sets and $S\cap T = \phi$, then $Sp(S\cup T)=Sp(S)\oplus Sp(T)$ .

Here's my answer:

I believe this statement is false, because it's possible that there are two vectors, $\underline{x}\in S\ ,\ \underline{y}\in T$ and some scalar $\alpha$ in the field $V$ is over so that $\underline{y}=\alpha\underline{x}$ . In this case the given parameters for $S$ and $T$ still hold true since $\underline{x}\neq \underline{y}$ so the intersection between them is still $\phi$, but now $Sp(S)+Sp(T)$ isn't a direct sum and is therefore not equal to $Sp(S\cup T)$ since the intersection between the two spans is not $\{\underline{0}\}$.

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes you are : it won't be a direct sum. To finish your proof, just present an easy counterexample as $T=\{1\}$ and $S=\{2\}$ in the vectorial space $\mathbb{R}$ (note that you could have $Sp(S)+Sp(T)=Sp(S\cup T)$ but the statement remain false.)

Comment: Yes! Awesome - thanks very much :) I'm reading over my answer and I think a better way to word it would be that given the case I've presented, $Sp(S\cup T)$ is no longer a direct sum between $Sp(S)$ and $Sp(T)$ .

Comment: Yes you can do that : there are two informations in the assertion $Sp(S\cup T)=Sp(S)\oplus Sp(T)$ ($=$ and $\oplus$), as soon as you show that one of them is not realise then you have your proof. You're welcome ^^